# Poco C++ Static Library (Crypto and SSL) Linker Error on OS-X

Tags: c++, macos, openssl, xcode6, poco-libraries

I have compiled Poco as static library to be used in an XCode6.1.1 Project. However I see linking error for libraries: libPocoCrypto.a and libPocoNetSSL.a:

I have already verified that these libraries are built for x86_64 architecture:

```
input file libPocoCrypto.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: libPocoCrypto.a is architecture: x86_64
```

What could be wrong? Any help would be appreciable?

Linker Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ASN1_STRING_data", referenced from:
      Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::extractNames(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, std::__1::set<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >&) const in libPocoCryptod.a(X509Certificate.o)
  "_ASN1_STRING_length", referenced from:
      Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::extractNames(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, std::__1::set<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >&) const in libPocoCryptod.a(X509Certificate.o)
  "_BIO_ctrl", referenced from:
      Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::load(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libPocoCryptod.a(X509Certificate.o)
      Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::save(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libPocoCryptod.a(X509Certificate.o)
      Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::save(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const in libPocoCryptod.a(X509Certificate.o)
  "_BIO_free", referenced from:
      Poco::Net::SecureSocketImpl::acceptSSL() in libPocoNetSSLd.a(SecureSocketImpl.o)
      Poco::Net::SecureSocketImpl::connectSSL(bool) in libPocoNetSSLd.a(SecureSocketImpl.o)
      Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::load(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in libPocoCryptod.a(X509Certificate.o)
      Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::load(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libPocoCryptod.a(X509Certificate.o)
      Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::save(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libPocoCryptod.a(X509Certificate.o)
      Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::save(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const in libPocoCryptod.a(X509Certificate.o)
  "_BIO_int_ctrl", referenced from:
      Poco::Net::SecureSocketImpl::acceptSSL() in libPocoNetSSLd.a(SecureSocketImpl.o)
      Poco::Net::SecureSocketImpl::connectSSL(bool) in libPocoNetSSLd.a(SecureSocketImpl.o)
  "_BIO_new", referenced from:
      Poco::Net::SecureSocketImpl::acceptSSL() in libPocoNetSSLd.a(SecureSocketImpl.o)
      Poco::Net::SecureSocketImpl::connectSSL(bool) in libPocoNetSSLd.a(SecureSocketImpl.o)
      Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::load(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libPocoCryptod.a(X509Certificate.o)
      Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::save(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libPocoCryptod.a(X509Certificate.o)
      Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::save(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const in libPocoCryptod.a(X509Certificate.o)
  "_BIO_new_mem_buf", referenced from:
      Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::load(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in libPocoCryptod.a(X509Certificate.o)
  "_BIO_s_file", referenced from:
      Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::load(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libPocoCryptod.a(X509Certificate.o)
  "_SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file", referenced from:
      Poco::Net::Context::Context(Poco::Net::Context::Usage, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Net::Context::VerificationMode, int, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libPocoNetSSLd.a(Context.o)
```

Comment: Possibly the order of linking. What does your command line look like (```-l``` switches in particular)

Comment: -lPocoCrypto -lPocoData -lPocoFoundation -lPocoJSON -lPocoNet -lPocoNetSSL -lPocoUtil -lPocoXML -lPocoZip -lcrypto -lpacparser.1 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework WebKit -framework Quartz -framework Security

Comment: Try ```-lPocoNetSSL -lPocoCrypto -lPocoNet -lPocoZip -lPocoUtil -lPocoXML-lPocoJSON -lPocoFoundation```. See [Library Order in Static Linking](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking). BTW, there's no point in linking PocoData without also linking SQLite,ODBC or MySQL.

Comment: It gives same error. However I think I have found the solution. I need to add explicitly libssl.a and libcrypto.a from openssl binary distribution in the linked frameworks and libraries in xcode. Ideally it should have picked the associated dylibs installed on the system.

Comment: It's a static build, right?

Comment: Yes it is a static build. So does it imply that we would need to explicitly  link it with the openssl static libraries? Also I have unfortunately ran into a problem even with a simple HTTP Request opened here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821524/error-using-statically-linked-poco-library-on-os-x-10-10-http-address-family-no . Is there anything special we need to configure while linking statically. Thanks a lot for your replies.

Comment: As one would reasonably expect, for static build you should link with static libraries, for dynamic - with dynamic one. See [Dynamic Library Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/OverviewOfDynamicLibraries.html)