# Error Using Statically Linked Poco Library on OS X 10.10: HTTP Address Family not supported

Tags: macos, poco-libraries

I am using POCO library 1.6.0 on OS X 10.10 and XCode 6.1.1 for building a mac application.

I have compiled it for static linking using the following configuration:

```
./configure --omit=Data/ODBC,MonoDB,Data/MySQL,Data/SQLite --config=Darwin64-clang-libc++ --static
```

This results in successful compilation and produces .a files.

I have linked the libraries in XCode under linked frameworks and libraries.

The app runs successfully.
Questions:

However on execution of Poco::Net::HTTPRequest to http://example.org, it fails with error : Net Exception Address family not supported. There is a closed issue here as well: https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/657.

This happens only when the Build Configuration is set to "Debug" and not "Release" which is strange.

Here is the code:

```
void test(){

Poco::JSON::Object result;
result.set("error", "0");
result.set("errorMessage","");
result.set("response","");
result.set("success", "true");

try {

    Poco::URI uri("http://example.org/?time=12345");
    Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());
    Poco::Net::HTTPRequest req(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET,uri.getPath(), Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
    req.set("User-Agent","Chrome/3.2");
    session.sendRequest(req); // sends request, returns open stream
    // Get response
    Poco::Net::HTTPResponse res;

    std::istream& is = session.receiveResponse(res);

    std::string str=std::string((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is)),
                                std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    std::cout<<str;

} catch (Poco::Exception& e) {

    result.set("error", 103);
    result.set("errorMessage",e.what()+e.message());
    result.set("success", "false");

}
std::ostringstream stream;
result.stringify(stream);
std::string str =  stream.str();

std::cout<<""<<str<<"";
}
```

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing any code. I suggest you start with [httpget](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/samples/httpget/src/httpget.cpp) example and work your way up from there. What you link with has nothing to do with HTTPRequest. Dynamic linking is with *.dylib, static with *.a

Comment: @Alex, I have edited to incorporate the code that I am using. I also tried the code from the link link that you have shared, however it fails with same error: Net Exception: Address family not supported. FYI, my piece of code works if I do a dynamic linking. Not sure what am I doing wrong..Your help is greatly appreciable.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I built and ran static httpget example on OSX with no problem.

Comment: Ok, I tried a bit more and have found that It happens only when the project is built in debug mode (which is by default) "DEBUG=1". Is there any particular issue with the static library and this flag. If i run this in release mode then it works fine. I have edited my question to reflect this. Any suggestions?

Comment: nope, both httpget and httpgetd work fine for me

Comment: Still able to reproduce this issue running on multiple machines OS-X 10.10. I am using libPocoNetSSLd.a and the problem is seen only in debug mode. Is there any dependency issue involved here?

Comment: Any chance you were able to find a solution for this @Anil? I'm having the same issue with Poco 1.6.1 in debug releases.

Comment: Try building openssl in a custom location otherwise Poco links with default openssl on OSX. This might be the reason that it works in release mode and not debug mode....To link with custom openssl: In configure command use `--include-path=$OPENSSL_INCLUDE_PATH`